# File system of iphone

Tags: iphone, file, system

How to access file system of iphone device?.Actually i have a task to send the files(.doc,.png,.mp3) through bluetooth ,basically file transferring  concept.But how to retrieve all the files stored in iphone device.Plz give me some idea regarding this.

Comment: it would help to know what operating system are you using?

Comment: @wim I dont think you got the question at all.

Comment: @amit you dont have the access to files in non-jailbroken iphone except the files that are in you apps main document bundle.

Comment: i want to transfer files such as sound file ,image file,or any file format but this file are not included in my iphone app.so,i need to get these file path from iphone file system.i hope it may be enough details to understand my question.

Comment: hey ..can u tell me what is this non-jailbroken iphone .

Comment: You can get the audio, Video and images from the Iphone using standard objective code and then send those files as nsdata.

Comment: about your question on non-jailbroken phone, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are using an iPhone that has not been jailbroken You can't use Bluetooth technology for sending files nor access the device's file system without a Mac or a PC.
  If Your device is jailbroken, You can do both.